# How to remove columns in a dataframe in R based on the values from another vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, multiple-columns

I have a list of values in a vector that i would like to use in deleting the columns found in a dataframe.

For example if my data frame has columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

and my vector has values of C,E,H

i would like my data frame to have columns

A,B,D,F,G,

Comment: Try `df1[yourvec] <- NULL` or `df1[setdiff(names(df1), yourvec)]`

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank You.

Comment: Also, df [ , !(names(df) %in% yourvec) ] should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options.  If we want to remove from the original dataset, assigning to NULL is quick

```
df1[vecofnames] <- NULL
```

Another option if we want to subset it to a different object

```
df2 <- df1[setdiff(names(df1), vecofnames)]
```

Or with `subset`

```
df2 <- subset(df1, select = -vecofnames)
```

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         select(-vecofnames)
```